# Git pre-commit hook to run lint check?

Tags: android, git, shell

how to Write a git `pre-commit hook` to run lint check for  change/newly added file,

currently, I'm running "./gradlew lint" command before commit, It would be much easier if there is a way to run the lint only for add/change files before committing to git.

Comment: hey, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get custom info
dirToLint=$(git config hooks.lintTargetDirectory)
lintArgs=$(git config hooks.lintArgs)

# If user has not defined a preferred directory to lint against, make it .
if [ -z "$dirToLint"]
  then
  dirToLint="."
fi

# Perform lint check

echo "Performing pre-commit lint check of ""$dirToLint"
lint $lintArgs "--exitcode" $dirToLint
lintStatus=$?

if [ $lintStatus -ne 0 ]
then
  echo "Lint failure."
  exit 1
fi

exit $lintStatus
```

put this in your .git/hooks/ folder as `pre-commit.sh`