# Run Android lint on specific files from CLI

Tags: android, command-line-interface, lint

How can I run "./gradlew lint" with some files as an argument?.
Eg: Run lint only on changed files before committing.

I am using a pre-commit hook to run lint on 'git commit' but it runs on the entire project instead of uncommitted files. Source:[Git pre-commit hook to run lint check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48738659/git-pre-commit-hook-to-run-lint-check)